# Python Pandoc filter: how to exploit an 'Image' key?

Tags: python, pandoc

I am writing a pandoc filter in Python for processing images (essentially changing the file location after a conversion).

Handling an Str key value easy, since it is a string ([from pandocfilters documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandocfilters)):

```
from pandocfilters import toJSONFilter, Str

def caps(key, value, format, meta):
  if key == 'Str':
    return Str(value.upper())

if __name__ == "__main__":
  toJSONFilter(caps)
```

I could find documentation about how to manipulate Blocks, but not images. What's the data structure?

```
if key == 'Image':
```

etc.?

This is what I would get, in native (Haskell) format:

```
[Image 
("",[],[("width","3.767361111111111in"),
("height","3.767361111111111in")]) 
[] 
(".doc1/media/image1.png","")
]
```

What should I do, to replace the extension of images from .png to .jpg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about key=='Image'.

That said, you can also use the [panflute](http://scorreia.com/software/panflute/code.html#panflute.elements.Image) library, which makes it a bit easier to manipulate images.

For [example](https://github.com/sergiocorreia/panflute-filters/blob/master/filters/png2jpg.py), this filter does what you need:

```
from panflute import run_filter, Image

def action(elem, doc):
    if isinstance(elem, Image):
        elem.url = elem.url.replace('.png', '.jpg')
        return elem

def main():
    return run_filter(action)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for mentioning this great package. This is exactly what I was looking for and it worked!

Comment: I tried to make few filters in haskell :https://github.com/prakashshaurya/PanaceaPanFilter.git here LinkKeyValueAppender.hs might help you , as well as others.